# Distance of subgroup to element in Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Given a (compact, closed) Lie group $G$ and a (closed) subgroup $H$, what is the distance of the identity to $Hg$ (or $gH$), where $g\in G$ and $Hg$ denotes the orbit under left-multiplication? The distance is to be measured in a natural left-invariant metric. Can one calculate it? Can one give an explicit formula for the geodesic joining the identity and the minimal distance point?

This seems like a natural question to ask, however, I cannot find anything about it (but then, I'm not to familiar with the geometry of Lie groups); or is this question so easy or difficult that there is no literature about it?

EDIT: Let's do an example. Take the unitary matrices $U(n)$ as a Lie group and the matrices

$$ \begin{pmatrix}{} U(r) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

as a subgroup $H$. I have no good intuition on how to calculate the distance between a point and that subgroup. I feel the path should be something like a "lift" of a geodesics in $U(n)/H$, but I can't put it together. I've also never seen a reference where something like this is done.

Comment: Since $L_{g^{-1}}$ is isometric, $d(e, gH) = d(g^{-1}, H)$. This is equivalent to ask: given a subgroup H and a point p, what is the minimal distance $d(p, H)$? Don't think we can get much without more information.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I just don't really get how to compute this quantity. I include an example that would help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

These are just some ideas, not an answer at all.

This is not so easy. First of all, that geodesic is not unique. (Even if $H = \{e\}$ is the trivial group). Neglecting this problem, let $e^{tX}$ be a minimal geodesic in $G$ joining $e$ to $e^X \in gH$. Then by minimality we see that $X$ is perpendicular to $h$, the Lie algebra of $H$. So $e^X = ge^{-Y}$ for some $Y \in h$. That is, given a $g$ you want to find $X\in h^\perp$ and $Y \in h$ so that

$$g = e^X e^Y $$

and in this case $d(e, gH) = ||X||$. But how to find this $X$ and $Y$? Also write $g = e^{X' + Y'}$, where $X' \in h^\perp$ and $Y' \in h$. So

$$e^{X' + Y'} =e^X e^Y$$

This seems to be a hard problem, unless ($G$ is abelian and in this case $X' = X$, $Y'=Y$).

Comment: That's exactly where I got stuck, too. It seemed to me that this is a natural question to ask and hoped that other people had already done some work on it. Thanks anyway for your thoughts.